# Prove: ${n\choose 1}-3{n\choose 3}+9{n\choose 5}-...=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}(-2)^n\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3}$

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

Prove: ${n\choose 1}-3{n\choose 3}+9{n\choose 5}-...=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}(-2)^n\sin\frac{2n\pi}{3}$

How to use binomial theorem on a left sum?

Comment: Look up multisection of series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could also start with $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)$ and use *[de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)*
in order to derive the binomial expression on the LHS.

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}(-1)^k3^k=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-2)^n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\qquad n>0\\
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We obtain for $n>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)&=\Im\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\Im\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)^n\\
> &=\Im\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}i^k\sin^k\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\cos^{n-k}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}(-1)^k\sin^{2k+1}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\cos^{n-(2k+1)}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}(-1)^k\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-(2k+1)}\\
> &=-\sqrt{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\sum_{k}\binom{n}{2k+1}(-1)^k3^k\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply *de Moivre's formula*.
- In (2) we take odd index values $2k+1$ since we need the imaginary part only.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** consider the binomial expansions of $(1+ix)^n$ and $(1-ix)^n$, their sum and their difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Binomial expansion of $\;\Bigl(\dfrac{1+\mathrm i\sqrt 3}2\Bigr)^n=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2n\mathrm i\pi}3}$.